# Samsung S6 Digitizer

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have been informed that the digitizer in my Galaxy S6 may be damaged. Is there any way to fix it? And is it even worth it to fix it or should I just dispose of the phone?

Edit: I no longer have this issue but can’t delete the question. This question may assist others who have this issue so maybe it’s a good thing I can’t delete it.

Comment: Yes, the idea of being helpful to others is exactly why you can't delete the question. We don't write answers here to just benefit one person :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to *fix* the digitiser, but it can be *replaced*. Your local phone repair shop can do that job for you. The parts and labour cost should be much cheaper than replacing the phone.

Comment: Thank you for this answer but I will be deleting this question as I have disassembled the phone to give the battery to a friend who has a functional S6.

Comment: (Just realized I cannot delete the question)